# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: discord.py

I am making a bot that mutes people when they join a vc. However, when I run the following code I receive an error about 'self' not being defined. How would I fix this?

```
async def join(ctx, *, member=discord.Member):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    await member.edit(mute=True)
```

Comment: Are you doing this inside the cogs? If you are, just try to put the first parameter `self`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside a Class/Cog you need to pass `self` as the first parameter.

```py
async def join(self, ctx, *, member=discord.Member):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    await member.edit(mute=True)
```